# How can I tell if a USB WiFi dongle is working?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, usb

I am trying to get a generic 802.11N USB WiFi dongle to work in a MacBook Pro running Sierra which allegedly has a dodgy WiFi chip (though it works most of the time), to help out a friend.

It shows up in System Information as a USB device by MediaTek (no model or more information just "802.11 n WLAN" device name. Some sort of Ralink software was already installed by the owner...but he says it's not working.

However I have no idea how to tell which WiFi device is actually being used. How can I determine this - is there a way to turn of the onboard WiFi specifically or see which device is being used?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can turn off the native wifi on mac OS.

1. Click on the Apple logo (top left)
2. Select Network
3. Pick your native wifi from the left device options
4. Click on the Turn Wi-Fi Off button on the right side

You're done!

Comment: So the dongle doesn't hook into the OS WiFi controls, it has a totally separate interface?

Comment: @Mr.Boy You ask how to disable the native WiFi on macOS.  I gave you directions on how to achieve that.  This way you ensure that you are using the dongle.

Comment: No I didn't ask that.

Comment: "However I have no idea how to tell which WiFi device is actually being used. How can I determine this - is there a way to turn of the onboard WiFi specifically or see which device is being used?" ??

Comment: Yes, that was a minor sub-part of my question, I don't know why you're fixating on it. Turning off native WiFi was your answer to my problem, fine. I ask you a question about that and you want to turn it into an argument... you still haven't answered my first comment.

Comment: No... Not trying to argue, and not fixated on the sub-part of your question.  You see, when trying to provide an answer - We, in the community require a bit more detail than what you have provided.  So, the sub-part of your post had the most detail, which triggered a response :-).  Anyway... Since we don't know the model number of your USB adapter (found on the HW itself), it's kinda difficult to provide any kind of answer or solution.  Have you looked at this site to download the specific mac driver for your device? https://www.mediatek.com/products/connectivity-and-networking/broadband-wifi

Comment: @Mr.Boy - I'm only trying to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way to test your dongle is, if you use `ifconfig`, you can list all your network interfaces. Find the interface you're interested in and then you can run `traceroute -i YOUR_INTERFACE SOME_IP_ADDRESS` where `YOUR_INTERFACE` is the interface you want to test and `SOME_IP_ADDRESS` is your gateway IP address, a public Internet address, or any other IP you want to see if you can reach via the wifi adapter.